# Get specific values from the OneToMany relationship in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I want to get only specific values in the JSON response when getting all rents. For example, I want to get only the User's Email and Username. With the current code, I get all the values from the table User. What do I need to change to achieve what I want to do? Further documentation about this kind of problem is more than welcome! :)

I have the following classes: Rent and User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rents")
@Data
public class Rent extends BaseModel {
ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_from;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_to;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name="users")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends BaseModel implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

@NotBlank
private String username;

@NotBlank
private String password;

@CreatedDate
public Long created;

@LastModifiedDate
private Long lastUpdate;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Builder.Default
private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
}

@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "triggeredBy", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
private List<Warning> warnings;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Rent> rents;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private Group group;
}
```

Furthermore, I have Request and Response classes:

```
@Data
public class RentRequest {
@ApiModelProperty(example = "12345")
@NotNull
private Device device_id;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_from;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_to;

@NotNull
private User user_id;

public Rent toRent() {
    Rent rent = new Rent();
    rent.setDate_from(this.date_from);
    rent.setDate_to(this.date_to);
    rent.setUser(this.user_id);
    return rent;
}

@Data
public class RentResponse(){
public RentResponse(){

}

public RentResponse(Rent rent) {
    if (rent != null) {
        this.date_from = rent.getDate_from();
        this.date_to = rent.getDate_to();
        //this.control = rent.getControl();
        //this.device_id = rent.getDevice_id();
        this.user_id = rent.getUser();
    }
}

@ApiModelProperty(example = "12345")
@NotNull
private Device device_id;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_from;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private long date_to;

@ApiModelProperty(example = "1584359718")
@NotNull
private User user_id;

public List<RentResponse> toList(List<Rent> rentList) {
    List<RentResponse> rentResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Rent rent: rentList)
        rentResponseList.add(new RentResponse(rent));
    return rentResponseList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you pass **id** as a parameter to the controller class in order to get the user details. You need to user **ArrayList** or **List** to get the thing done. First thing is fetch user's details to the **ArrayList** or **List** by passing id. I will provide simple example. In this example Users class is the model and UsersRepository is the repository class and UsersController is the controller class. Here List is used to get store all the details regarding to the id. Method in the UsersRepository will get all the details regarging to the passed id. Those details will be stored in a list you can't directly pass those details since it contains all details of that id. So, using for-each loop specific data(email,username) will be fetched and stored in a array. If you wants you can directly return this array. But in this case I put these array indexes again to an ArrayList and this ArrayList will be returned. So that it only return email and username.

**Users Class**

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private int age;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(int id, @NotNull @Email String email, @NotNull String username, @NotNull String password, @NotNull int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**UsersRepository Class**

```
package repository;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

    List<Users> findUsersByIdIsLike(int id);

}
```

**UsersController Class**

```
package controller;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import repository.UsersRepository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @PostMapping(path = "/singleData")
    public ArrayList<String> getSingleUserData(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
        // get all data to the list using related to the id using the method in UsersRepository class
        List<Users> userAccountList = (List<Users>) usersRepository.findUsersByIdIsLike(id);

        String singleDetails[] = new String[2];

        if (userAccountList != null) {
            for (Users userAccount : userAccountList) {
                singleDetails[0] = userAccount.getEmail();
                singleDetails[1] = userAccount.getUsername();
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // put data in singleDetails to an array list so that array list will be returned
        dataArrayList.add(singleDetails[0]);
        dataArrayList.add(singleDetails[1]);

        return dataArrayList;
    }

}
```

This will be helpful for your job.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using DTO projections. Its a different approach, rather than returning the entity Rent, you will return the RentDTO class

You will just populate the required fields in the RentDTO using JPQL or CriteriaBuilder/CriteriaQuery APIs

Have a look at this great article https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/